# How to bind onclick event to elements of a class permanently

Tags: jquery

I can attach the onclick event to a function,

```
$(".options").click(function(){ alert($(this).val())})
```

But `.options` elements are replaced all the time based on user interaction. How can I set it so that I dont have to execute this statement each time I create an `.option` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: using event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.options', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Longer answer: the above, but attach the delegation target as far down the document tree as you possibly can without risking it being removed (or closest to where you are adding the options) as opposed to simply `document`; doing this makes sure that the click event doesn't hit the delegation target for all clicks on the page.

```
$('some existing element').on('click', '.options', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: could you give some documentation too? Can can `some existing element` be a class instead of an id?

Comment: Sure, you could even target multiple elements; just be aware that click handlers will be attached to every element you specify, so keep the number of elements to a minimum.